# Getting error while setting Database value in drop down list using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting the following error while trying to set the DB value using Angular.js.

> Error:

```
TypeError: index.push is not a function
```

I am explaining my code below.

```
<tr ng-repeat="d in days">
<td>{{d.day}}</td>
<td> <select class="form-control"  id="catagory" ng-model="catagory" ng-options="cat.name for cat in listOfCatagory track by cat.value " ng-change="removeBorder('catagory',$index,catagory.value);" >
 </select></td>
<td>
<select class="form-control"  id="subcatagory+$index" ng-model="subcatagory[$index]" ng-options="sub.name for sub in listOfSubCatagory+$index track by sub.value " >
<option value="">Select Subcategory</option>
</select>

</td>
<td><input type="text" name="comment" id="comment" class="form-control oditek-form" placeholder="Add Comment" ng-model="comment" ng-keypress="clearField('comment');"></td>
</tr>
```

When user is selecting the value from first drop down list the below part is executing.

```
$scope.removeBorder=function(id,index,catvalue){
        var catdata=$.param({'action':'subcat','cat_id':catvalue});
        $http({
            method:'POST',
            url:"php/customerInfo.php",
            data:catdata,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        }).then(function successCallback(response){
            //console.log('sub',response.data);
            angular.forEach(response.data,function(obj){
                var data={'name':obj.subcat_name,'value':obj.subcat_id};
                $scope.listOfSubCatagory+index.push(data);
            })
        },function errorCallback(response) {
        })
    }
```

I am getting error at this `$scope.listOfSubCatagory+index.push(data);` line.Please help me to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

You are using **ng-change="removeBorder('catagory',$index,catagory.value);"**

where **$index** returns **the index of element in the list** , which is an **integer** .

You are trying to call .push() function on an integer that's why you are getting this error .

Comment: i need to make `$scope.listOfSubCatagory+index` to `$scope.listOfSubCatagory0`,`$scope.listOfSubCatagory1`..etc..

Comment: for that you can try $scope['listOfSubCatagory' + index] , it will create a key in  $scope which can be accessed as $scope.listOfSubCatagory0 ... etc.

Comment: @ p2: I did as per you but same error came in same line.

Comment: don't do index.push() , index is an integer , there is no push function for an integer . push function works for array objects . I don't have your code so i am not able to debug your problem properly . Try to work on  index.push() part .

Comment: I have already given the code .Please check my post view part is already there.

Comment: try this :   
angular.forEach(response.data,function(obj){
                var data={'name':obj.subcat_name,'value':obj.subcat_id};
                $scope['listOfSubCatagory'+index] = data
            })

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104497/discussion-between-satya-and-p2).